# Python - Changing the format of the bottom values to show the month

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

New to python and pandas, I got my function working correctly by looking for existing code however I want to change the bottom values from numbers to actual texts, which in this case would be months.

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering as AC

def scale_df(df,axis=0):
    return (df - df.mean(axis=axis))/df.std(axis=axis)


colormap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)
def plot_hmap(df, ix=None, cmap=colormap):
    if ix is None:
        ix = np.arange(df.shape[0])
    plt.imshow(df.iloc[ix,:], cmap=cmap)
    plt.colorbar(fraction=0.03)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(df.shape[0]), df.index[ix])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(df.shape[1]))
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()

def scale_and_plot(df, ix=None):
    df_marginal_scaled = scale_df(df.T).T
    if ix is None:
        ix = AC(4).fit(df_marginal_scaled).labels_.argsort() # a trick to make better heatmaps
    cap = np.min([np.max(df_marginal_scaled.values), np.abs(np.min(df_marginal_scaled.values))])
    df_marginal_scaled = np.clip(df_marginal_scaled, -1*cap, cap)
    plot_hmap(df_marginal_scaled, ix=ix)

month_by_type = crimeDataMonth.pivot_table(values='Month', index='Crime type', columns=crimeDataMonth.index.month, aggfunc=np.size).fillna(0)

 plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
 scale_and_plot(month_by_type)
```

[image]

My table is the following which has the month:
[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample of `month_by_type` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you would like to change the labels in the x-axis of the plot from the numbers [0, 1, ... 11]
to the names of the corresponding months ['January', 'February', ... 'December'].

If so, you could do that using this:

```
# Get the current locations of the labels
locations, labels = plt.xticks()
# Set the values of the new labels
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
# Place the new labels
plt.xticks(locations, labels=months)
```

You could do this with less hard-coded values using the `calendar` module:

```
import calendar
locations, labels = plt.xticks()
months = [calendar.month_name[n] for n in range(1, 13, 1)]
plt.xticks(locations, labels=months)
```